# How to replace a value of an attribute in JS function on run time?

Tags: java, javascript, html, parsing, html-parsing

I am working on my Java application that (besides other things) produces HTML. In this HTML I need to change a value of one attribute inside one JS function every time I run it. The process is like this:

```
1. Every time I run HTML, my application connect to MySQL database and retrieves some needed values.
2. Those values are then parsed into HTML and replacing some keywords which are set for the purpose of replacing.
```

I have done already replacing some text by defining keyword `DataText` in my HTML

```
<p>DataText</p>
```

And in my Java application, I made a replacing like this:

```
public void visitStringNode (Text string)
        {
          ...

            else if (string.getText().equals("DataText")){
                  string.setText(text);
            }
        }
```

where `text` is a String retrieved from the database. Then I wanted to do the same with replacing a value of one attribute within my JS function by setting a keyword `DataVideo` :

```
function replaceSrcc() {

    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0];
        copy = elem.cloneNode();
    copy.src = DataVideo;
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, elem);
    }
```

and in Java make the replacing similarly as in a previous case:

```
else if (string.getText().equals("DataVideo")){
                      string.setText(video_link);
                }
```

where `video_link` is a String containing youtube link retrieved from the database. This, however, does not work. Debugging says that is just simply fails to search for `DataVideo` keyworkd within HTML. Any suggestions?

---

EDIT : The function ReplaceSrcc() is called on page load, just like this:

```
<script>
function replaceSrcc() {

    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0];
        copy = elem.cloneNode();
    copy.src = "https://www.youtube.com/v/SKQeNnNT_Vg?version=3";
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, elem);
    } 


    if (window.addEventListener){
         window.addEventListener('load', replaceSrcc, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', replaceSrcc);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: MichalB: where are you calling the function replaceSrcc() ?

Comment: in HTML, defined within <body> element.

Comment: are you calling the function on page load or on some event? could you paste that code as well?

Comment: you are using `string.getText().equals`, this suggests that you are first splitting your HTML into words or (more likely) xml nodes and comparing to those. I think you need to ask yourself, why did you expect `DataVideo` to be identified as a single xml node?

Comment: @Ritesh: I have done it, but I think that is not exactly the problem. The problem is that parser just fails to search for DataVideo keyword and replace it by a retrieved string. So I think the problem is in my Java function which is trying to search for this keyword.

Comment: @DavidMcMullin: I have done it since it worked with replacing XML nodes and just somehow didnt think about it, but I think you got a point. But how to access the content of <script> tag?

Comment: well, you could try actually searching (Java strings do in fact have methods like `contains` and `replace`) although that may hurt your performance. Why are you trying to roll your own parsing solution anyway? Is this homework?

Comment: The thing is I am accessing the database within Java application, not in HTML, so I have to firstly parse the retrieved value to HTML and then replace it. No PHP or some other server-side technology.

Comment: yes, and what's wrong with JSPs?

Comment: I still do not understand, but if you mean why did I make an edit of my question and put that JS parser, it is because of the user Rishet, who asked me for that. Otherwise I do not understand your question.

Comment: MichalB: I dont know whether I am right or not but I think:  copy.src = DataVideo; here it should be copy.src = "DataVideo"; Parser fails to search for DataVideo, it could be because it is never set. I think your parser code of java should be right as it is working for "DataText"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages